# SAAS CSS css fix wraped in a custom class name?

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material, saas

So i have this long css element selector for angular material md-tab active text. I want to change the text color of tab label when the tab gets active , i found online that this is the selector to go by and it works, but i am working on a large project, so i only want to change a specific md-tab not the every md-tab on the project. so how can i wrap this long selector with a class name? so this way only when i use this class name this selector will be in play.

```css
md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active, md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active md-icon, md-tabs.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active md-icon, md-tabs.md-default-theme.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-focused, md-tabs.md-default-theme.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-focused md-icon {
  color: rgb(130,152,86) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your css in a class, which is written where you are using your specific md-tab.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-div-used-this-md-tabs">
    <md-tabs></md-tabs>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.my-div-used-this-md-tabs {
  md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active, md-tabs > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active md-icon, md-tabs.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-active md-icon, md-tabs.md-default-theme.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-focused, md-tabs.md-default-theme.md-accent > md-tabs-wrapper > md-tabs-canvas > md-pagination-wrapper > md-tab-item:not([disabled]).md-focused md-icon {
    color: rgb(130,152,86) !important;
  }
}
```